# Commands to step into and step over, outside of visual pane mode

Tags: debugging, radare2

The [Radare book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/introduction/basic_debugger_session.html) says

> Use <kbd>F7</kbd> or s to *step into* and <kbd>F8</kbd> or S to *step over* current instruction.

But, I don't see it telling you how to do this with the `d` command. When I run `d?` I see

```
ds[?]                   Step, over, source line
dc[?]                   Continue execution
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did't find this to be too intuitive, but the answer is `ds`. Now it makes sense though: `ds` expands to a bunch of stuff,

```
[0x55673eccb5fa]> ds?
|Usage: ds Step commands
| ds               Step one instruction
| ds <num>         Step <num> instructions
| dsb              Step back one instruction
| dsf              Step until end of frame
| dsi <cond>       Continue until condition matches
| dsl              Step one source line
| dsl <num>        Step <num> source lines
| dso <num>        Step over <num> instructions
| dsp              Step into program (skip libs)
| dss <num>        Skip <num> step instructions
| dsu[?]<address>  Step until address
| dsui[r] <instr>  Step until an instruction that matches `instr`, use dsuir for regex match
| dsue <esil>      Step until esil expression matches
| dsuf <flag>      Step until pc == flag matching name
```

While *really* cool, there are a tons of ways to `step` and they're all organized under `ds`.

- <kbd>F7</kbd> is step into, or `ds`
- <kbd>F8</kbd> is step over, or `dso`